# Multiple checkout with the same entry_id

Tags: expresso-store, entryid

I have a product which a visitor can enter your own amount. 
Now this product is several times can be ordered with a different amount.

Is this possible?

http://www.inescoffee.be/site/aankoopbon

Bert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add multiple of the same items to the same cart. If the item is exactly the same (i.e. Large Blue Shirt) they will show up under the same item:

> 2 - Shirt (Large, Blue) - $15/each - $30

If they have different modifiers or a different price Store does not consider them the same item so it would show up in 2 lines

```
1 - Shirt (Large, Blue) - $15/each - $15
1 - Shirt (Large, Red)  - $17/each - $17
Total                              - $32
```

Comment: Dear, 

With a modifier that will not work, customers can set their prices themselves. This with the Custom Prices option. example: http://demo.exp-resso.com/store/product/donation 

I really want to create a multi-donation with the same entry-id. 

Can this work?

Comment: If the price is different it shouldn't be a problem of having the same product show up multiple times in the same cart.

Comment: If you are using the user defined price. In the past I have used the custom price functionality and a hidden text modifier to pass in either the title of the charity and/or a date so that even simile priced items for seperate charities showed up in the cart as seperate items